# jQuery Smartmenus parent item of dropdown clickable bootstrap website

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, drupal-7, parent

I have [this Bootstrap 3 website](http://landberg.at/nl). I use [jQuery Smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org) for the menu. I want the parent item to be clickable on the dropdown links. I thought I had this working before, but now the parent item is not clickable.

How do I make the parent item clickable within my Bootstrap theme with the jQuery Smartmenus plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/menu/menu-link.func.php`

Comment out line 43:

```
// $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
```

Comment out line 44:

```
// $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
```